# XMLStarlet ed -s gives usage error on 1.3.1, works on 1.6.1 -- what changed?

Tags: xml, bash, xmlstarlet

Im using xmlstarlet for editing a few xml config files. The default file looks like this:

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name></name>
    <value></value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name></name>
    <value></value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

I am adding a couple more `<property>` subnodes. like this:

```
    sudo xmlstarlet ed -L \
      -s '//configuration' -t elem -n "property" \
      -s '//configuration/property[last()]' -t elem -n "name" -v "test-1" \
      -s '//configuration/property[last()]' -t elem -n "value" -v "00001" \
      -s '//configuration' -t elem -n "property" \
      -s '//configuration/property[last()]' -t elem -n "name" -v "test-2" \
      -s '//configuration/property[last()]' -t elem -n "value" -v "00002" \
      /etc/path/to/file.xml
```

I tested this locally, with XMLStarlet 1.6.1, and it worked great and exactly how I wanted it to. The result looks like this:

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name></name>
    <value></value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name></name>
    <value></value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>test-1</name>
    <value>00001</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>test-2</name>
    <value>00002</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

However when I put this in a shell script and then tried running it on my remote instance (with XMLStarlet 1.3.1), it keeps printing out the help text for the package like when you just type `xmlstarlet` in the terminal. I have no idea what could be causing this

```
[remote-machine ~]$ xmlstarlet
XMLStarlet Toolkit: Command line utilities for XML
Usage: xmlstarlet [<options>] <command> [<cmd-options>]
where <command> is one of:
  ed    (or edit)      - Edit/Update XML document(s)
  sel   (or select)    - Select data or query XML document(s) (XPATH, etc)
  tr    (or transform) - Transform XML document(s) using XSLT
  val   (or validate)  - Validate XML document(s) (well-formed/DTD/XSD/RelaxNG)
  fo    (or format)    - Format XML document(s)
  el    (or elements)  - Display element structure of XML document
  c14n  (or canonic)   - XML canonicalization
  ls    (or list)      - List directory as XML
  esc   (or escape)    - Escape special XML characters
  unesc (or unescape)  - Unescape special XML characters
  pyx   (or xmln)      - Convert XML into PYX format (based on ESIS - ISO 8879)
  p2x   (or depyx)     - Convert PYX into XML
<options> are:
  --version            - show version
  --help               - show help
Wherever file name mentioned in command help it is assumed
that URL can be used instead as well.

Type: xmlstarlet <command> --help <ENTER> for command help

XMLStarlet is a command line toolkit to query/edit/check/transform
XML documents (for more information see http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/)
```

`xmlstarlet ed -s` is valid in both of these versions; what changed, to make my script version-specific?

Comment: Run `bash -x yourscript`. What xmlstarlet commands does it show the script actually invoking?

Comment: (By the way, given that there's a [nonzero history of vulnerabilities in libxml/libxslt](http://www.cvedetails.com/product/14676/Xmlsoft-Libxslt.html?vendor_id=1962), using `sudo` there is not ideal. Even if you need escalated privileges to read the input file, you can escalate only the read, and not the processing: `sudo cat /etc/path/to/file.xml | xmlstarlet ...`; similarly, to escalate only output priviliges, `xmlstarlet ... | sudo sponge /etc/path/to/file.xml` -- ideally with `pipefail` enabled, so a failure anywhere in the pipeline causes a correct exit status of failure).

Comment: (above uses `sponge` from [moreutils](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/) to only write output on close, but of course the write-to-tempfile-and-rename approach is workable too, and allows for better error-handling).

Comment: Backing up, though -- the main thing this question needs to be answerable is steps someone else can use to get the same problem. Running `bash -x yourscript` will log the actual commands being run, which will probably give you what you need to formulate those steps, by seeing what else is going on in your script -- this may even be all you need to solve the problem yourself, or formulate a question better focused on an immediate cause.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - it shows my command being invoked i.e. `$ bash -x xs.sh
+ sudo xmlstarlet ed -L -s //configuration -t elem -n property -s '//configuration/property[last()]' -t elem -n name -v test-1 -s '//configuration/property[last()]' -t elem -n value -v 00001 -s //configuration -t elem -n property -s '//configuration/property[last()]' -t elem -n name -v test-2 -s '//configuration/property[last()]' -t elem -n value -v 00002 /etc/path/to/file.xml`

Comment: Hmm. That generally looks like it should (and ought to be edited into the question). Next question: How do the versions of XMLStarlet compare between your dev and production platforms? Which release are you testing with (on your dev system where everything works), and which release are you using in production (where the failure takes place)?

Comment: (`xmlstarlet --version` from both platforms should suffice).

Comment: (my current guess is that your remote platform has a version that doesn't support `-L`).

Comment: Remote is 1.3.1 and local is 1.6.1

Comment: Hmm. That's old, but not so old as to not have `-L`.

Comment: trying `yum update xmlstarlet` shows up as `No packages marked for update`

Comment: yeah, what updates your distro does/doesn't have isn't something we can help you with here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138869/discussion-between-charles-duffy-and-newkid101).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XMLStarlet 1.3.1 (which you have on your remote system), the `-v` argument to `xmlstarlet ed -s` is mandatory.

Thus, you need to add `-v ''` when adding the `property` elements.

```
sudo xmlstarlet ed -L \
  -s '//configuration' -t elem -n "property" -v '' \
  -s '//configuration/property[last()]' -t elem -n "name" -v "test-1" \
  -s '//configuration/property[last()]' -t elem -n "value" -v "00001" \
  -s '//configuration' -t elem -n "property" -v '' \
  -s '//configuration/property[last()]' -t elem -n "name" -v "test-2" \
  -s '//configuration/property[last()]' -t elem -n "value" -v "00002" \
  /etc/path/to/file.xml
```